# Enabling button when zipcode is valid - is not working

Tags: jquery, validation

I have implemented jquery to validate zipcode. in focusout() event of the location text box.

It disables the submit button, if the zipcode is not valid.

I am facing one problem here.

1. User enters an invalid zipcode, trying to click submit, then the button is disabled and giving an error message.
2. User changes the zipcode to the right format and then clicks the submit button, Button has to be enabled now. 
   --------But here it is still disabled and error message is still showing.
   ---------If you try to change the focus to some other input field everything works well.

Including the code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#locationInput").focusout(function(){ 
var value = $("#locationInput").val();

//If the value give in location field is numeric, it is guessed to be a zipcode
if($.isNumeric(value))
{
    $("#hidden").val("zipcode");

    //Zipcode validation for USA
    var postalCodeRegex = /^([0-9]{5})(?:[-\s]*([0-9]{4}))?$/;

    if(postalCodeRegex.test(value))
    {
        $("#error").html("");
        $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        var value = $("#hidden").val();
        //alert("Valid zipcode");
    }
    else
    {
        //alert("Invalid zipcode");
        $("#error").html("Please provide a valid zipcode (Ex: 95035) or city name");
        $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
else
{
    $("#hidden").val("city");
    //alert("false");
}

});
</script>

<br />
```

Do anyone know where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the best way to validate zip code in your case, is using keyup event so user can see is current zip code valid after every edition

```
$("#locationInput").keyup(function(){
    if(--validatin here--){
        $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else{
        $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I already tried it with keyup event. In that case hidden value is storing.                                 Am I missing anything here.

Comment: What do you mean "hidden value is storing"? You can use the same code as you wrote before, just change event from focusout to keyup and all should work as before, only validation be executed after every key pressing. Also you can add a Timeout to prevent several validation in a row, when user types fast, but for zip code I don't think that it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.                            Found the problem (I had changed the value of the test variable "value" somewhere inside. So It kept on going into the else block. Now IT works, both with the focusout and keyup event. Sorry for the inconvenience.                                                       Yes it may not be needed for zipcode. But I am pretty new to javascript/jquery. I couldn't find any easier ways, So I thought I will start with the basic one. I will try to explore more on this. Thanks for the input.